# How to load all other elements before iframes

Tags: dom, iframe, pageload

I have a client that wants a lot of different iframe elements loaded on to a certain page, several bandcamp players, vimeo etc...

The iframes are being loaded below the hero of the page, but when the page is loaded, instead of all the hero content being loaded first, and then the iframes populating once the hero content is loaded, the iframes seem to interrupt elements that (should) load first.

Is there a way to prioritize the hero content to load before the iframes? I've seen this asked a few times here, but all answers seem to suggest the order in which elements are coded, not stalling iframes specifically until after other content is loaded.

Any help / direction is much appreciated!
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is probably to create the `iframe`s dynamically (e.g. using jQuery) once the page has fully loaded (with the `.ready` handler in jQuery for instance).

Comment: Thanks @jcaron I'll research creating iframes dynamically with jQuery and let you know how it works out.